# Service Hook of Pull Request created is not being triggered when Pull request is created through Team Services REST API

Tags: rest, tfs, azure-devops, pull-request, slack

I'm trying to integrate my Visual Studio Team Services with Slack, and the first thing I tried to do was notify my Slack channel whenever a Pull request is created.

So I searched through the options, and the best fit so far was the Service Hooks available on Team Services, which integrate seamlessly with Slack, or does it?

The problem I encountered was: I use a tool that creates pull requests through the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/git/pull-requests#Createapullrequest), and the service hook doesn't seem to be working when I create pull requests through this method, only when using Team Services UI.

This is the [Service Hook configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkXBw.png).

Has anyone faced the same problem, or know any other way of notifying a pull request creation to slack?

Comment: Is the pull request created successfully with REST API?

Comment: Yes, it shows up on TFS like expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue has been fixed by Microsoft, the last update of Team Services triggers the event without a problem now.